# How to remove a subview from memory and display right away?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, subview

How do I remove a UIImageView's subview (a View Controller in this case) from memory and display immediately?

```
[myGroovySubview release];
```

isn't doing it.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks // :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myGroovySubview.hidden = YES;` hides the view. You could also try to remove it from its superview with `[myGroovySubview removeFromSuperview];`

If you removed it from its superview, the `release` call should automatically remove it from memory since the reference count should be zero after that call.

Comment: if some view controller has retained it as a property, then the release may not remove it from memory.